# Assign a value from another variable after a check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have encountered this behavior with this variable which I cannot understand why.

This is my code:

```
Monitoring(){
 this.arrayTimestamp.push(`${buf.readInt16LE(0)}`);
        this.firstElementArray = this.arrayTimestamp[0];
}

StopFunction(){
    console.log("this.firstElementArray: ", this.firstElementArray , "this.firstElementArraySaved ", this.firstElementArraySaved)
    // for example the result is firstElementArray: -5516, firstElementArraySaved: 20
        if (this.firstElementArraySaved !== "") {
          this.firstElementArray = this.firstElementArraySaved;
          console.log("firstElementArray: ", this.firstElementArraySaved, " firstElementArraySaved: ", this.firstElementArraySaved)
    // this console.log print firstElementArray: 20, firstElementArraySaved: 20
        }
    
        Promise.all([disconnect1, disconnect2]).then(() => {
          console.log("this.firstElementArray : ", this.firstElementArray, " firstElementArraySaved: ", this.firstElementArraySaved)
    //this print another time firstElementArray: -5516 and firstElementArraySaved : 20
          Actions.activity({
            firstElementArraySaved:this.firstElementArraySaved
```

As you can see in the comment that I wrote, in the if I have `firstElementArray = 20`  and `firstElementArraySaved = 20`. But then in the console log before Actions.activity, `firstElementArray` is equal to`-5516` and so the action pass the value `-5516` instead of `20`.

How can I do to assign the value to `firstElementArray` from `firstElementArraySaved`?

Thank you so much

EDIT:

Basically `this.firstElementArray` takes element from arrayTimestamp[0]

Comment: So what is updating the property? It is impossible to tell from what you provided.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't understand why the assignment doesn't work. Is it theoretically right this way?

Comment: The assignment *works*. However, some other code must be updating the property again.

Comment: Ok I'm editing my question

Comment: Based on the added code, I'd assume that `Monitoring()` is called automatically, which updates `this.firstElementArray` before the promise is completed.

Comment: @VLAZ right because in the middle I do a splice, I saved the first value of the array in the `this.firstElementArraySaved`

Comment: @VLAZ Is the situation a little clearer like this? Or am I trying to explain myself better? :)

Comment: OK, so the issue *is* that `Monitoring()` is called. I'm not sure why that would be an issue, though. If you don't need `this.firstElementArray` to be updated, then don't update it. If you *do* need to constantly update it, then don't use it in the promise - save the information in a different variable and use that.